# Iterando en un Map en Java

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con un ejercicio de java, ¿se puede iterar 2 veces sobre un *Map*? estoy buscando tener acceso a los nombres que están dentro de un map.

```
Map<String, String[]> nombreAlumnos=new HashMap<String, String[]>() ;

nombreAlumnos = { primero=[[Rodrigo],[Maria],[Paola]], segundo=[[Daniela, Amelia, Santiago]]}
```

Puedo tener el acceso a los *keys* pero en base a ese *key* me gustaría poder tomar todos sus valores (los nombres dentro de cada *key*).

Este es el código que estoy utilizando para iterar sobre `nombreAlumnos`:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : names.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
            //busco iterar sobre los valores dentro de este key
}
```

Cuando trato de iterar me muestra el siguiente error:

> Cannot invoke length() on the array type String[]

Resultado esperado:

> ```
> System.out.println(primero[0]);
> ```
>
> "Rodrigo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se como hiciste el llenado, pero como lo expresas no me funcionó. De igual manera te dejo lo que hice para obtener la información que requieres.

```
Map<String, String[]> nombreAlumnos = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String[] primero = { "Rodrigo", "Maria", "Paola" };
String[] segundo = { "Daniela", "Amelia", "Santiago" };
nombreAlumnos.put("primero", primero);
nombreAlumnos.put("segundo", segundo);

for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : nombreAlumnos.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());

    /**
     * Aqui hacemos el recorrido de lo que tenemos en el getValue().
     * Se hace mediante un for para obtener todas las posiciones dado que
     * como lo especificaste en un comienzo es de tipo String[]
     */
    for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos,